# How to determine when and where $2$ objects collide and evaluate the reasonableness.

Tags: vectors

> $2$ Objects, $A$ and $B$ move in $3D$ space such that their positions over time $(t ≥0)$ are described by the following vectors until they collide.
> $$r_a =\cos(at)\hat i + 2\sin(at)\hat j  -\sqrt{3}\cos\left(at\right) \hat k\\r_b = \frac{bt}{2}\hat i+\sqrt{3}bt\hat j+\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}\hat k$$
> a) Given that $-\pi ≤ a ≤ 0$, determine when and where the objects collide. and then evaluate the reasonableness.

My working:

First of all, I am not asking anyone to do this for me but just verify my work. My teacher refused to reply any of my fricking email so I have to come here for help.

First let $x =\cos(at) = \frac{bt}{2}$

and $y = 2\sin(at) = \sqrt{3}bt$

$z = -\sqrt{3}\cos(at) = \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}$

Therefore I conclude that $b = -1$ by comparing $x$ and $z$?

I then used the $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta$ to find $t$ which is $1$?

Now I found $t$ and $b$, I can substitute into the equation and find the position when they collide?

and $y = 2\sin(a) = -\sqrt{3}$

for $t = 1$ and $b = -1$.

I use this to verify?

Comment: It is correct. You get $(x,y,z)=(bt/2,\sqrt3bt,\sqrt3t/2)=(-1/2,-\sqrt3,\sqrt3/2)$. Further $\cos(a)=-1/2$ gives $a=\pi/3-\pi$.